# Accessing web application running inside a docker container in host browser?

Tags: docker, jira

I have installed a JIRA trial version inside a docker container. Installation completes fine:

```
Please wait a few moments while JIRA Software starts up.
Launching JIRA Software ...
Installation of JIRA Software 7.7.0 is complete
Your installation of JIRA Software 7.7.0 is now ready and can be accessed
via your browser.
JIRA Software 7.7.0 can be accessed at http://localhost:8080
Finishing installation ...
```

but I am not sure how to access it from a browser on my host. When I access http://localhost:8080 from my host browser I hit another web application that is currently running on that port.

I have tried to change the port to 8087 and restart jira but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What command did you use to start the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should point it to `0.0.0.0:8080` when you run docker container instead of localhost. .and then you can access it from host machine with `localhost:8080`

and also, you should first stop another application from using the same port..to avoid port conflict with `docker-proxy`

Comment: What do you mean by point to? Do I need to pass 0.0.0.0:8080 to the docker run command?

Comment: yes.. like `-p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080` . . actually,, it usually automatically point to `0.0.0.0` when you run docker container,, i dont know why yours is `localhost:8080`